# Кастомный контроллер на канве

Tags: android, android-layout

Доброго времени  суток.

Есть  наследник  класса view,  в  нем на  канве  отрисовываются кастомные кнопки.
Как  его  подключить в  xml разметке?

**Обновление**

Ну, я  так и пытался:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <com.planningtask.planningtime.ControllerTime/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Получил:

> 11-16 21:38:07.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(30791):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
> start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.planningtask.planningtime/com.planningtask.planningtime.StartLaunch}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary
> XML file line #7: Error inflating
> class
> com.planningtask.planningtime.ControllerTime

Comment: Например, класс MyControllerView находится в каталоге ru.my.app, тогда в xml он будет выглядеть вот так: 
 
    <ru.my.app.MyControllerView  
        android:layout...  
    </ru.my.app.MyControllerView>

Comment: получил:
11-16 21:38:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(30791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.planningtask.planningtime/com.planningtask.planningtime.StartLaunch}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.planningtask.planningtime.ControllerTime

Comment: Добавьте классу конструкторы (Context c), (Context c, AttributeSet as), (Context c, AttributeSet as, int def) и перенесите в них имеющуюся инициализацию.

Comment: Спасибо, только не понимаю, что в них инициализировать

Comment: @alexmx, под инициализацией я имел в виду тот код, который у вас (наверно) есть в вашем конструкторе. Сейчас всё оформлю и перенесу в ответ.

Comment: Там паинты, ректы. Я не корректно выразился, их повторно в остальных двух конструкторах инициализировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, класс `MyControllerView` находится в каталоге `ru.my.app`, тогда в xml он будет выглядеть вот так:

```
<ru.my.app.MyControllerView  
    <!-- здесь расписываете все нужные атрибуты -->  
</ru.my.app.MyControllerView>
```

Если вы наследуетесь от `View` и хотите подключить элемент из xml-разметки, то помимо текущего конструктора (например, `(Context mContext)`) вы должны сделать как минимум ещё один ИЛИ заменить его:

```
public название_класса(Context con, AttributeSet set) {
    //Вот сюда переносим весь код из
    //Старого конструктора, а его убираем
}
```

Остальные конструкторы, используются редко и крайне редко соответственно:

```
public название_класса(Context con) {}
public название_класса(Context con, AttributeSet set, int ds) {}
```

**Обновление**

Да, иначе получите ещё один вылет. Минимальный "набор" атрибутов - `android:layout_width` и `android:layout_height`.

Comment: Все понял, все разжованно))), а атрибуты обязательны?

Comment: @alexmx, Обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю))

Comment: А я вот не понял, в каком месте в классе написано android:layout_width?